# When is the `apply` method fired on a Laravel global scope object?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm attempting to implement a global scope in Laravel 4.2 by [following the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes). I have created a `UserTypeTrait` to add a `UserTypeScope` to the global scope. This is my `UserTypeTrait`:

```
trait UserTypeTrait
{
    public static function bootUserTypeTrait()
    {
        Log::info('bootUserTypeTrait fired');
        static::addGlobalScope(new UserTypeScope);
    }
}
```

This is my `UserTypeScope`:

```
class UserTypeScope implements ScopeInterface
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        Log::info('apply fired');
        $model = $builder->getModel();
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {
        // @todo
    }
```

I'm attempting to apply this trait to my `Customer` object:

```
class Customer extends User
{
    use UserTypeTrait;
}
```

Whenever the application boots, I'm getting confirmation that the `bootUserTypeTrait()` method fired in my log file. I'd like to add a constraint to all queries related to my `Customer` model in the `apply` method of my `UserTypeScope`, but I can't figure out how to trigger the `apply` method. From the documentation, it seems that it should be triggered any time I query the model. I've tried a few tests, but none of them result in the `apply` method being fired. For example:

```
public function testUserTypeScopeApplyFires()
{
    FactoryMuffin::create('Users\Customer');
    $customers = Customer::all(); // this does note fire `UserTypeScope::apply()`
    $customer = Customer::first(); // neither does this
}
```

In my log file, I see plenty of `bootUserTypeTrait fired` and no `apply fired` entries. When is the `apply()` method invoked? I thought I followed the documentation correctly. Am I missing something?